# Dynamically Adding To database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

## multi-tenant ROR app

--

I'm trying to figure out how to call different databases from `database.yml`:

```
#config/database.yml
#Defaults
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

dev: &dev
  <<: *default
  username: *****
  password: *****
  host: ******

##########################

#Admin
development_admin:
  <<: *dev
  database: *******

##########################
```

I'd like to make the `database` key a variable, so it can be set like this:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true 
  establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_admin", database: "our_db")
end
```

The problem is an error occurs as follows:

[image]

---

I'm sure there's a way to fix it - I'm interested to hear if anyone has any method to fix the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If correctly understood the question:

```
con = Rails.configuration.database_configuration["#{Rails.env}_admin"]
establish_connection(con.merge('database' => 'our_db'))
```

Or, if simple use configuration:

```
establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_admin")
```

Comment: Wow thank you for this information - I will try this in a few minutes, when I go to office!